# Objective-C block memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Here is my class:

```
@implementation Test

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}

- (void)let {
    __weak Test *weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        __strong Test *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!strongSelf) {
            NSLog(@"self is released");
            return;
        }

        NSInteger i = 0;
        while (i < 90400000) {
            i++;
            if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
                NSLog(@"%ld", (unsigned long)i);
            }
        }
    });
}

@end
```

And the method where I am calling the method `let`:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        Test *test = [Test new];
        [test let];
        [test release];

        int k = 0;
        while (0 == 0) {
            k++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is the following:

```
1000000
2000000
3000000
4000000
.
.
.
88000000
89000000
90000000
dealloc
```

You should know that my `Test` class is using ARC and the `main` method is not using ARC.

In this case as far as I know, because the weak-strong dance, the block is not retaining `self`. So, based on this code the retain count of the `test` object should be 1 after the execution of the `let` method. Exactly after I call the `let` method I've released the `test` object, so the `test` object should be deallocated instantly as far as I know, but the log is not representing this. Why is the `test` object is deallocated only after the block ends the execution?

Comment: The block is not retaining `weakSelf`, but on your first line you then make a strong reference to it again.

Comment: Good point... :) But why it is recommended then to add the if to strongSelf?

Comment: Because you may need it.  weakSelf prevents the block **object** from holding a strong reference to self which is important for cases where the block object is stored for future use.

Comment: @InfinitePossibilities To prevent self from being deallocated _during_ the execution of your block.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't use weakSelf for a block going directly into a dispatch queue because you aren't creating a retain cycle.

Comment: The weak/strong dance avoids a retain cycle (also called a "strong reference cycle") where the block and `self` both strongly point to each other. But `strongSelf` will be released when the block returns, so there is no retain cycle.

Comment: Imagine a world in which it takes 10 minutes for that block to be executed because there's a million other things on the queue. Weakifying self allows self to be deallocated at any point _before_ that block is executed. However, if the block gets executed _before_ others stop caring about self then the strongify _guarantees_ that self won't be deallocated until the block finishes executing.

Comment: As a side note, we are dealing with undefined behavior in this exact case.  ARC could easily detect that strongSelf is not used in the rest of the function and release it immediately after assignment.

Comment: Ok, good. My last question, will a block always retain pointers in it?

Comment: Blocks make a _copy_ of pointers used inside of it. This increments reference counts. Use the __block keyword to use the original reference inside the block instead of a copy.

Comment: What do you mean by making a copy? They call the copy method? I'm assuming not, because the copy method doesn't increments the reference count. Do you mean copying the pointer address and not the pointer's value? Am I right?

Comment: Any auto pointer variable declared outside of the block and used inside the block will be copied into the block with the same storage class as defined (strong, weak, autoreleasing).  It gets more complex if you use __block.

Comment: That's good, but please explain what do you mean exactly by copying a pointer?

Comment: @InfinitePossibilities The _pointer_ is copied, not the object. This means that if you redirect your pointer _inside_ of the block, it will not affect the original pointer. Similar to how in objective-c input parameters to methods are "pass by value", the same is true for blocks. Using the `__block` keyword allows for "pass by reference" behavior.

Comment: A new struct is created to hold all the variables. In your example, the struct { __weak Test *weakSelf }.  The value is then assigned and because it is weak, not retained but added to the weak reference tracker.  That struct lives in memory until there are no references to the block.

Comment: Cool, now I understand everything, thanks!